# increase image size in Sweave using RStudio

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, sweave

I would like to increase the size of images in a Sweave document so that its width matches that of the text. The only way that is supposed to do that which I could find is using width and height, e.g. <>=, but the only thing this does is decrease the size of the points, axe ticks and labels. The total size of the image stays the same. And the parameter for one R code block seems to affect all other code blocks. I'm using Sweave in RStudio.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

blablablabla blablabla bla bla blabla blablablabla bla bla bla blablablablablablabla blabla
\begin{figure}[h]
<<bla1, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
plot(1:100,1:100, xlab="blabla",ylab="blabla",main="blabla")
@
%\caption{blablabla}
\end{figure}

% \begin{figure}[H]
% <<bla2, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE, width=30, height=30>>=
% plot(1:100,1:100, xlab="blabla",ylab="blabla",main="blabla")
% @
% \caption{blablabla2}
% \end{figure}
% 
% \begin{figure}[H]
% <<bla3, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE, width=2, height=2>>=
% plot(1:100,1:100, xlab="blabla",ylab="blabla",main="blabla")
% @
% \caption{blablabla3}
% \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `out.width="\\textwidth"`  ... ?

Comment: like this:<<bla1, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE,out.width="\\textwidth">>=? Doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate this.  I'm using RStudio 0.99.489, R version 3.2.2, `packageVersion("knitr")` is 1.11, using the "Compile PDF" button.  I tweaked the file a little bit to take advantage of some of `knitr`'s capabilities (e.g., specifying `fig.caption` and `fig.pos` automatically embeds the picture in a figure environment with the appropriate positioning spec ...)  I also removed `fig=TRUE` and your `SweaveOpts{}` statements since these are obsolete ...  and made the text width even wider (50% wider than `\textwidth`) so the effect would be obvious.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

blablablabla blablabla bla bla blabla 
 blablablabla bla bla bla blablablablablablabla blabla
<<bla1, echo=FALSE, fig.pos="h", fig.caption="BLA", out.width="1.5\\textwidth">>=
plot(1:100,1:100, xlab="blabla",ylab="blabla",main="blabla")
@


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have RStudio Version 0.98.1091. It seems to include the \SweaveOpts automatically and your code doesn't include the image in the file at all. Will try newest RStudio version.

Comment: Tried it with 0.99.489. Same problems.

Comment: I have knitr 1.8, but is that used for Sweave?

Comment: How are you building?  With the `Sweave()` command?  You shouldn't use that, `knitr` dominates it in every way.  Either click the "Knit PDF" button in RStudio, or use `knitr::knit2pdf` ...

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. However there seems to be a lot of Sweave syntax which is not longer valid with that approach.